# MissingGreenlet: greenlet_spawn has not been called; can't call await_only() here. Was IO attempted in an unexpected place?

Tags: python, async-await, python-asyncio, fastapi, alembic

I am trying to perform alembic migrations but receiving the error 'sqlalchemy.exc.MissingGreenlet: greenlet_spawn has not been called; can't call await_only() here. Was IO attempted in an unexpected place? '

I've added expire_on_commit=False but I did not help. Are there any ideas how to solve it?

models.py

```
import enum
from datetime import datetime
from typing import List

from sqlalchemy import DateTime, ForeignKey, func
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import AsyncSession
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase, Mapped, mapped_column, relationship
from typing_extensions import Annotated
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import AsyncAttrs

time_ = Annotated[
    datetime,
    mapped_column(nullable=False, server_default=func.CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()),
]


class Base(AsyncAttrs, DeclarativeBase):
    pass


class Role(enum.Enum):
    USER = "user"
    ADMIN = "admin"
    MODERATOR = "moderator"


class Group(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'group'

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(nullable=False, index=True)
    created_at: Mapped[datetime] = mapped_column(default=datetime.now)
    user: Mapped[List["User"]] = relationship(back_populates="group", lazy="selectin")
    user_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey('user.id'))



class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(nullable=False)
    surname: Mapped[str]
    username: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(index=True)
    phone: Mapped[str]
    email: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(unique=True)
    role: Mapped[Role] = mapped_column(nullable=True)
    group: Mapped[Group] = relationship(back_populates="user", lazy="selectin")
    image: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(nullable=True, default='image.jpg')
    is_blocked: Mapped[bool]
    created_at: Mapped[datetime] = mapped_column(default=datetime.now, nullable=True)
    modified_at: Mapped[datetime] = mapped_column(
        default=datetime.now, onupdate=datetime.now, nullable=True
    )
```

db_settings.

```
class DbSession:
    def __init__(self, host: str, engine_kwargs: dict[str, Any] = {}):
        self._engine = create_async_engine(host, **engine_kwargs)
        self._sessionmaker = async_sessionmaker(autocommit=False, bind=self._engine, expire_on_commit=False)

    async def close(self):
        if self._engine is None:
            raise Exception("not initialized")
        await self._engine.dispose()

        self._engine = None
        self._sessionmaker = None

    @contextlib.asynccontextmanager
    async def connect(self) -> AsyncIterator[AsyncConnection]:
        if self._engine is None:
            raise Exception("DatabaseSessionManager is not initialized")

        async with self._engine.begin() as connection:
            try:
                yield connection
            except Exception:
                await connection.rollback()
                raise

    @contextlib.asynccontextmanager
    async def session(self) -> AsyncIterator[AsyncSession]:
        if self._sessionmaker is None:
            raise Exception("DatabaseSessionManager is not initialized")

        session = self._sessionmaker()
        try:
            yield session
        except Exception:
            await session.rollback()
            raise
        finally:
            await session.close()


# sessionmanager = DbSession(settings.DB_URL, {"echo": settings.echo_sql})

sessionmanager = DbSession(settings.DB_URL)


async def get_db_session():
    async with sessionmanager.session() as session:
        yield session
```

Comment: Did you init alembic by `alembic init -t async migrations`?

Comment: alembic doesn't support async access to database for example using `asyncpg` driver (e.g. `postgresql+asyncpg://usr:root@db/db`, instead you should use normal URL without `+asyncpg`

Comment: Any luck with this one? I am having the same issue now